# Why wont the meta-api show Instagram direct messages?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am using the v14 meta-api and I am trying to send a request to show all the direct messages on an Instagram business account. Using the graph-api tool I am sending this request:

{page-id}/conversations?platform=instagram and getting this as a response:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I'm assuming this means it thinks there are no direct messages, however there are, there should be 2 that are in the response. Also when I try it without the ?platform=instagram it gives me a response with the messages I've received on Facebook. Has anyone seen this before?

As I said it works for just my Facebook messages but not for my Instagram messages. I've dug through the docs and cant see why this is happening. I am trying to get this set up so I receive webhooks for Instagram direct messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I know this behavior. If there are messages and you have not approved the contact, the messages are not available in the Graph API. As soon as the contact is approved in the Instagram App, the messages appear.

ATM, I'm looking for some API call to approve the new contact without app interaction, but no luck so far.